# How to prevent duplicate PayPal payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a simple Pay Now button, the code created through the button maker, with a "custom" hidden field added to identify it.
I wonder if there is some additional hidden field I can add to tell PayPal that "This transaction should not be made twice".

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="{MYUNIQUEID}">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="{MYHOSTEDBUTTONID}">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" 
    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

</form>
```

As it is now it's unlikely that the customer should be able to pay twice, but I noticed that when the Sandbox had a glitch I succeeded in paying the same transaction twice. Something that I absolutely want to avoid. Not just for the customer, that could get refunded, sure, but also since I don't want my database messed up and I would like to avoid extensive coding to catch duplicate payments...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would want to add a unique identifier to the "invoice" parameter; `<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="your unique invoice ID">` and enable "Block duplicate payments" within the 'Profile' > 'My selling tools' section on your account at www.paypal.com

Answer (score 8):

Thanks Robert! (above post)

I actually went so far that I was going to ask PayPal Merchant Technical Support about it and just before submitting my question there found a page with the answer -

Avoiding duplicate payments: 
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/165

Not sure if you have to log in to see above page so I'm quoting the page here for convenience:

> You can avoid duplicate transactions by passing an invoice number to
>   the PayPal system.  This feature is available for Website Payments
>   Standard, and Website Payments Pro (SOAP and NVP).  The PayPal system
>   will check to make sure the invoice number you pass has not already
>   been paid in your account, as long as you have configured your profile
>   to block duplicate invoice numbers.
>
> Example:  Invoice 001 has been paid, therefore if 001 is passed to the
>   PayPal account a second time, it will be denied.
>
> To block this in your profile:
>
> Block accidental payments: You may prevent accidental payments by
>   blocking duplicate invoice IDs
>
> 1. Login at https://www.paypal.com
> 2. Click the 'Profile' subtab
> 3. Under 'Selling Preferences' click 'Payment Receiving Preferences'
> 4. Choose 'Yes, block multiple payments per invoice ID' if you wish to utilize this feature while passing the "invoice" variable
> 5. Scroll to the bottom and click the 'Save' button
>
> To pass the invoice number for Website Payments Standard, you will
>   need to add a line of code to your existing button code.  You cannot
>   add this code to a button originally created as encrypted.  Example
>   below:
>
> For Website Payments Pro, the parameter you pass depends on the type
>   of API calls you are making.
>
> For SOAP:  InvoiceID
>
> For NVP:  INVNUM
>
> When using Pro, if a duplicate invoice number is detected the error
>   10412 will be returned.  For a complete list of the API error codes,
>   and details regarding the 10412 error [Click Here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes)