# Can I verify paying users with a client-side script?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When a user logs in using PayPal on my website, how can I verify he has paid using the PayPal APIs alone? I don't want to store customer data on my side, as I only need to check with PayPal whether the user has paid in order to grant him access.

Can I use just a JavaScript script client-side to:

1. authenticate the user with PayPal
2. check whether his account matches my payment records on PayPal
3. authorize those who have paid and block those who haven't?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at #2 in your question, I think that you'll have to store some customer data on your website (Username / Password) at the very least.

So, since you already have a database, I would recommend that you at least store a few things regarding payment, such as:

1) Exact date and time of payment
2) If payment was completed successfully
3) (optional) if payment was refunded / cancelled

Paypal is just a way of transferring money, but not a subscription manager.  If you don't keep some of the information stored on your end, it could lead to problems like this: [Paypal subscriptions IPN - problem with users subscribing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527710/paypal-subscriptions-ipn-problem-with-users-subscribing-multiple-times?rq=1)

Thankfully, you don't have to store any sensitive information.

Comment: No, I don't have a database of my records, PayPal has. Setting up one is what I'm trying to avoid. Since PayPal has all the necessary data for authentication and verification of a payer, can't I query PayPal directly to identify the user and check if he's paid or not? That's all I need for authorization, and a database w/ server-side coding appears very unnecessary & insecure :(

Comment: I think your users will feel a bit strange if they have to provide PayPal credentials each time they want to use your site.  IMO, people will only want to deal with PayPal when they make the payment.  There are a variety of CMS's that you can start out with, that are quite secure.  Many of them have PayPal plugins.  Check out Joomla.